# Is it possible to render a component passed in as a Prop to a Higher Order Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

I am working on increasing my knowledge of Higher Order Components.  I am wondering if it is possible to render a "component," which is passed in as a prop to a higher order component "SuperCommentList."  To my knowledge there is no way to render a component as "this.props.component" or even as an instance variable "this.WrappedComponent."  I know this does not follow traditional HOC conventions, but was trying to determine if this was possible.  I am receiving the errors below.  Can anyone advise how I can achieve this?

Warning:

> Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> . Did you accidentally export a JSX literal
> instead of a component?
> at App

Error:

> react-dom.development.js:28439 Uncaught Error: Element type is
> invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a
> class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
>
> Check the render method of `App`.
> at createFiberFromTypeAndProps (react-dom.development.js:28439:1)
> at createFiberFromElement (react-dom.development.js:28465:1)
> at reconcileSingleElement (react-dom.development.js:15750:1)
> at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:15808:1)
> at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:19167:1)
> at updateContextProvider (react-dom.development.js:21154:1)
> at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21649:1)
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
> at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
> at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)

HOC Call

```
import CommentList from "./CommentList";
import data from "../utils/data";
import modelClass from "../utils/Model";
import SuperCommentList  from "../utils/SuperCommentList";

const CommentListWithSubscription = withSubscription(CommentList, model.data);

function withSubscription(WrappedComponent, selectedData) {
  const color = { color: selectedData.color };
  return <SuperCommentList selectedData={selectedData} component={WrappedComponent} color={color}/>;
}
```

HOC Example below:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

class SuperCommentList extends Component {

   WrappedComponent;
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      console.log("WithSubscription props:", props);
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

      this.WrappedComponent = this.props.component;
      this.state = {
        data: this.props.selectedData,
      };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      // ... that takes care of the subscription...
      this.handleChange();
    }

    handleChange() {
      this.setState({
        data: this.props.selectedData,
      });
    }

    render() {
      console.log("WithSubscription State Data:", this.state.data);
      return <this.WrappedComponent data={this.state.data} {...this.props.color}/>;
    }
  }

  export default SuperCommentList;
```

Comment: What part of your code does not work ? Looks fine, besides the weird looking`<this.WrappedComponent ..>` which should work regardless. You could do `const {WrappedComponent} = this;` in the `render` and then use it directly as `<WrappedComponent ...>` if you want it to look cleaner.

Comment: I have added the warning and error to my original question (see above).

Comment: How do you use the return from `withSubscription` it looks like you intend to use it as a component `<CommentListWithSubscription />` but you are returning a ReactNode from `withSubscription`. Does updating `withSubscription`'s return to `return () => <SuperCommentList /*props here*/ />;` fix your issue?

Comment: @JacobSmit, The results of WithSubscription are currently being returned in a Route.  No that did not resolve the issue.
 
<Route exact path="/withSubscription" element={<CommentListWithSubscription/>} />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the HOC need to return a component, not a rendered DOM node.

So change the HOC to

```
function withSubscription(WrappedComponent, selectedData) {
  const color = { color: selectedData.color };

  return function ComponentWithSubscription() {
     return <SuperCommentList selectedData={selectedData} component={WrappedComponent} color={color} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: After adding the code above, I was able to return the component as follows:
return <this.props.component data={this.state.data} {...this.props}/>;